How long should one wait before declaring that an author "did not comment"?
Around a week ago, I sent an email to the author of an article published in an independent blog, requesting comment on a claim for which I cound find no evidence (and, in fact, not insignificant proof to the contrary). This was my first time contacting an author to request comment.
I'm wondering, how long after an attempt to establish communication would it be appropriate to say that a person did not comment / was unreachable for comment? Is there an accepted standard or any specific factors that should be considered?

To say in which context? That will make a big difference. E.g. to say it to your colleague in a conversation, to post it publicly on your website, to state it in a publication ....

Also, a week is very, very short. People are travelling, on vacation, busy with work, teaching, etc. Also, answering random requests might not be high on their to-do list or your email might have even landed in their spam folder. How long ago hat the blog been published? If some time has passed, chances are the contact is no longer working.

You can't "demand" a quick response from someone with whom you have no relationship. Perhaps they consider you a crank and will never respond.

Not seeing what this has to do with "academia". Seems like you're looking for standards in journalism. A blog post isn't an academic article. The question is tagged "peer review" but has nothing to do with academic peer review, and a blog post certainly isn't peer reviewed.

Simple:

I reached out to Jane Doe by email on October 21, 2024, requesting a clarification, and have not yet received a response.

Leave it to your readers or interlocutors to interpret whether you are being impatient or not, in the context of the blog author, the date of publication of the original post, and so forth.

I think what OP wants to know is how long they need to wait to ensure a good chance that behaving in the way that you suggest will not be interpreted by readers as impatient behavior. The "leave it to your readers" suggestion does not answer that question.

The author has no obligation to reply comments. If this is a peer-reviewed publication which you think might be wrong, you can write and submit a comment (which will be peer-reviewed too), then the editors would normally contact the authors to ask for their opinion. Otherwise you can just hope that they reply or try to approach them at a conference, but I would not claim anywhere that the authors "did not comment", as there is nothing they should comment on until you publish something yourself.
